# Optimizing query for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to tune the query below which runs in a loop and values for `minprice` and `maxprice` are dynamically substitued.

```
select * 
from product 
where name = 'a' 
  and minprice >= 0 
  and maxprice <=10
```

so in loop there will be multiple query with different values

```
select * 
from product 
where name = 'a' 
  and minprice >= 40 
  and maxprice <=70

select * 
from product 
where name = 'a' 
  and minprice >= 50 
  and maxprice <=60
```

One way is to write a stored procedure and do all the looping for different prices at database level.

Is there any other way to tune so that there will be single query with multiple dynamic values

Comment: Show us the complete procedure (**[edit]** your question by clicking on the [edit] link below it, do **not** post code in comments)

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a set oriented langauge, it works best when there are no loops, as it gives the optimizer the best possible way to achieve you end results.

If currently to you are doing

```
for i in (select * 
            from product 
           where name = 'a' 
             and minprice >= 0 
             and maxprice <=10 )
loop  
    --inserting/updating/deleting  
    insert into another_table values(1.product_id,i.name);
end loop;
```

change that to

```
insert 
   into another_table
select producr_id,name 
  from product 
 where name = 'a' 
   and minprice >= 0 
   and maxprice <=60;
```